# Curious about the name of a specific .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm curious if .NET and C# would allow me to include a control as such into my WinForms application?

[image]

This is a screenshot of how it looks like in Visual Studio 2010.

PS. Sorry for being too vague. I guess I'm looking for the name for this control.

Comment: I'm a few days late, and Emmad Kareem already answered your question, but there's a really cool article on CodeProject with a "Property Bag" control. It behaves similarly to the .NET PropertyGrid control, except it's a bit more flexible in that you can dynamically assign properties to it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12282/Implementing-a-PropertyBag-in-C

Comment: @sab669: Very good. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called PropertyGrid control. See: [PropertyGrid](http://www.dotnetperls.com/propertygrid)